# How to create a field in in a preexisting table with VBA for MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a Database `Database` and a table `Table`.  I have found online how to create a field from a newly created database and table in VBA in MS Access, but I do not know how to do this when the database and table already exist before the macro has been run.

To do it without a preexisting database and table, I can run the following:

```
Sub CreateTable()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim table1 As DAO.TableDef

    Set db = CurrentDb

    Set table1 = db.CreateTableDef("ExampleTable")

    With table1
        .Fields.Append.CreateField("newField", String)
    End With
```

But how could I adapt this to add the same field to a preexisting table?

Or more specifically, how do I modify

```
Set table1 = db.CreateTableDef("ExampleTable")
```

So that `table1` points to an existing table in the `db` database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a field to an existing table by executing an Access DDL statement.

```vb
Dim strDdl As String
strDdl = "ALTER TABLE ExampleTable ADD COLUMN newField TEXT(255);"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strDdl
```

In `TEXT(255)`, 255 is the field size --- the maximum number of characters that field can contain.  And 255 is the absolute upper limit for an Access text field.  When creating a `TEXT` field from the `ADODB.Connection.Execute` method, you must include a value for field size.  Choose a smaller value if you prefer.

When you create a new field using DAO methods, as in your question, the field size for a text field is optional.  However, when you don't specify a size, Access uses the *"Default text field size"* setting from your Access options.

Comment: What is the `255` in `TEXT(255)` for?

Comment: Added explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this. Just reference the table name in the `TableDefs` collection rather than creating one.

```
Public Sub CreateTable()

Dim table1 As DAO.TableDef
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef

' Create the new Table Def object
Set table1 = New DAO.TableDef

' Name the Table
table1.Name = "Test"

' Create the new Field
Set fld = New DAO.Field
fld.Name = "newField"
fld.Type = DataTypeEnum.dbText

' Append the Field to the table
table1.Fields.Append fld

' Append the table to the Table Def Collection
' Without this the table just lives in memory
CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append table1

' Create another Field
Set fld = New DAO.Field
fld.Name = "newField2"
fld.Type = DataTypeEnum.dbText

' Append the New Field to the EXISTING table
CurrentDb.TableDefs("Test").Fields.Append fld

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!  Would you mind just commenting the code a tiny bit?  There's a couple parts that are unclear to me (I'm not very experienced with VBA)